# Stripping punctuation from unique strings in an input file

Tags: python, string, punctuation

This question ( [Best way to strip punctuation from a string in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/265960/best-way-to-strip-punctuation-from-a-string-in-python) ) deals with stripping punctuation from an individual string. However, I'm hoping to read text from an input file, but only print out ONE COPY of all strings without ending punctuation. I have started something like this:

```
f = open('#file name ...', 'a+')
for x in set(f.read().split()):
    print x
```

But the problem is that if the input file has, for instance, this line:

```
This is not is, clearly is: weird
```

It treats the three different cases of "is" differently, but I want to ignore any punctuation and have it print "is" only once, rather than three times. How do I remove any kind of **ending** punctuation and then put the resulting string in the set?

Thanks for any help. (I am really new to Python.)

Comment: Are you sure you want to open the file in `a+` mode? `r` should be enough.

Comment: You're correct that r is enough, however I'm hoping to later append to the file so I might as well put a+ there for future purposes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import re

for x in set(re.findall(r'\b\w+\b', f.read())):
```

should be more able to distinguish words correctly.

This regular expression finds compact groups of alphanumerical characters (a-z, A-Z, 0-9, _).

If you want to find letters only (no digits and no underscore), then replace the `\w` with `[a-zA-Z]`.

```
>>> re.findall(r'\b\w+\b', "This is not is, clearly is: weird")
['This', 'is', 'not', 'is', 'clearly', 'is', 'weird']
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip about regulars, hadn't known about them.

Answer (score 0):

You can use translation tables if you don't care about replacing your punctuation characters with white space, for eg.

```
>>> from string import maketrans
>>> punctuation = ",;.:"
>>> replacement = "    "
>>> trans_table = maketrans(punctuation, replacement)
>>> 'This is not is, clearly is: weird'.translate(trans_table)
'This is not is  clearly is  weird'
# And for your case of creating a set of unique words.
>>> set('This is not is  clearly is  weird'.split())
set(['This', 'not', 'is', 'clearly', 'weird'])
```